# Windows Phone 8 Image Hyperlink

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, hyperlink

I started to develop some apps for WP8 and I have one question.
so that's what i want to do:
create a new button on xaml mainpage file.
and when on click="butt1_Click" to show a new messagebox or something like this(maybe a new StackPanel) that will contain:

Item 1 , Item 2, Item 3....
 I will try to explain this in xaml and if someone can transform the code in C#..

```
    <Hyperlink 
Content="Item 1" Name="HyperlinkImage"
FontSize="18" Width="175" Height="75" 
Margin="140,350,140,185" NavigateUri="/Assets/myimage.png/"/>
```

I will explain this in HTML, maybe that way someone will understand what I want to do:

```
<a href="/Assets/myimage.png/"> Item 1 </a>
```

Thanks Alot!

Here's a little image on what I'm plaining to do:
http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/5769/zylk.jpg

Comment: Have you a page in your app for viewing the image?

Comment: Can I confirm what you're trying to do is: Have a number of options on screen in some sort of list. When each item is tapped a different image will be displayed. Is this correct? Where should the image be shown? on the same page? on a different page? Full screen?

Comment: I'll try to write a pseudo-code:
I have a page with buttons.
when user tap a button I want to open a new page where should be:
Hyperlinked items like: Street 1, Street 2. and when user tap on hyperlink the image is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

On MainPage.xaml add:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Image 1" Tag="/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png" Click="ImageButtonClicked" />
    <Button Content="Image 2" Tag="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" Click="ImageButtonClicked" />
    <Button Content="Image 3" Tag="/Assets/Tiles/FlipCycleTileMedium.png" Click="ImageButtonClicked" />
</StackPanel>
```

(Note that all buttons have the same event handler)

In MainPage.xaml.cs add:

```
private void ImageButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(
        new Uri("/ImagePage.xaml?path=" + 
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode((sender as Button).Tag.ToString()),
                UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Add a page ImagePage.xaml and add the following to it:

```
<Image x:Name="TheImage" />
```

Then in ImagePage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string path = "";

    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("path", out path))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
        {
            this.TheImage.Source =
                new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
    }
}
```

This lets you define in the XAML the image to show on a separate page when the button is clicked.
Hope this helps.

Comment: that's a good way to show the image right after the button is clicked..but I want after buton is clicked to open a new texbox with hyperlinked text, and when the text is hited it opens the image. I dont know if is that possibile :-(

Comment: I'll give an example: 
1. McDonnald's
2. KFC
3. ...
after user hits 1'st button on the next page are shown:
adress of McDonnals 1, adrr. 2; next user tap on adrres 1 and pop-up a map screenshot.

Comment: @ZaraGheorghe you asked about hardcoding those references in the XAML but that probably isn't the best way to do things. Create a new app using the "DataBound Application" template. It will show how to bind a list to a ViewModel and then show details of a particular item on another page. That's the technique I'd suggest for you. You could then add another page to show the image of the selected item (assuming that the image path is added to the view model item) either on another page or on the details page.